# How to find which libc version app links against?

Tags: application-development, shared-library

When building an application using g++, I am not explicitly passing the `libc` library as a library to link against in the same way you would do it for other libraries (like passing `-lpthread` for example).

I know that `libc` has the `libc.so.6` so name, but I am aware that this is not actually a library but something like a pointer to another version of `libc` (such as `libc-2.15.so`).

If I had multiple versions of `libc` on my computer, how can I tell which one actually gets used using `libc.so.6`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ldd` should be the tool of your choice. That gives you the shared library actually linked.

```
confus@confusion:~/misc/test$ ldd -r -v testendian
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbcfff000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1a5a4c5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1a5a8a5000)

    Version information:
    ./testendian:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

In case of the libc you can simply run the `.so` file and will be told the library version.

```
confus@confusion:~/misc/test$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10) stable release version 2.15, by Roland McGrath et al.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide some information what the ldd output tells me? Does it mean that `testendian` requires GLIBC_2.3 or GLIBC_2.2.5?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure, it means that the program needs GLIBC 2.2.5 and the library loader `ld-linux-x86-64`  was build with GLIBC_2.3. So both in a way. But take that with a grain of salt, as I didn't find a reference.

Comment: Works great for dynamic executables, but not so much for static ones! (I need to test what I'm linking against becauses of a gcc warning: `warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`)